# How to pass arguments to Command Prompt in c# code?

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, msbuild

With the code below I can only start Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt, but now I have to publish a web site to a target path on my local drive.

I need c# code which does something like the following command:

> msbuild /target:Build /p:BuildingProject=true;OutDir=C:\Temp\build\
>   ccosapp.sln My first attempt (fails - doesn't do anything):

Below is the code I tried, which doesn't do anything:

```
ProcessStartInfo oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat", @"msbuild C:\Users\Johan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PRJAPP\PRJAPP.sln");
oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
oInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
oInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
oInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(oInfo);
System.IO.StreamReader oReader2 = p.StandardOutput;
string sRes = oReader2.ReadToEnd();
oReader2.Close();
```

Another attempt (also fails):

```
string strCmdText = "/k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\" && msbuild /p:OutDir=C:\\Temp\\build \"C:\\Users\\Johan\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\CCOSApp\\ccosapp.sln\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

I'm getting the error in my CMD window:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

The last attempt (fails as well - getting the same error as in my 2nd attempt):

```
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
/// Executes a shell command synchronously.
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><param name="command">string command</param></span>
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><returns>string, as output of the command.</returns></span>
public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
{
    try
    {
        // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
        // and "/c " as the parameters.
        // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
        // and then exit.
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + command);

        // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        // Get the output into a string
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the command output.
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
}

/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
/// Execute the command Asynchronously.
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><param name="command">string command.</param></span>
public void ExecuteCommandAsync(string command)
{
    try
    {
        //Asynchronously start the Thread to process the Execute command request.
        System.Threading.Thread objThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));
        //Make the thread as background thread.
        objThread.IsBackground = true;
        //Set the Priority of the thread.
        objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        //Start the thread.
        objThread.Start(command);
    }
    catch (ThreadStartException objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
}

string cmdStr = @" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat""
                  cd ""C:\Users\Johan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CCOSApp""
                  msbuild /target:Build /p:BuildingProject=true;OutDir=C:\Temp\build 
                  ccosapp.sln";
new VsFunctions().ExecuteCommandAsync(cmdStr);
```

Comment: `ProcessStartInfo` has an `Arguments` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came with this workaround:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\publish.bat");
w.WriteLine(@"call ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat""");
w.WriteLine(@"call cd ""C:\Users\Johan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CCOSApp""");
w.WriteLine(@"call msbuild /target:Build /p:BuildingProject=true;OutDir=C:\Temp\build ccosapp.sln");
w.Close();

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"publish.bat");
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\";
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.Start();
```

1. I create a .bat file.
2. I write the commands in it.
3. Finally I start the .bat file as a Process.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

you are getting this error because there is space in your path, between `Program` and `File`

try placing double quotation mark at the start and end of your path

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the whole path of the executable, try to changing the directory to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\" via

```
oInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\";
```

Then just call the vcvarsass.bat

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you use the `Arguments` property of `StartInfo`

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"msbuild C:\Users\Johan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PRJAPP\PRJAPP.sln";
cmd.Start();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

ie like in this example: [Using cmd.exe from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696953/using-cmd-exe-from-c-sharp)